# Webpack and GLSL shaders

Tags: webpack, glsl

I'm working on a Sage Wordpress site and want to implement some WebGl via the [Three.js](https://threejs.org/) library. Like this [code drops example image hover](https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/webgl-mouseover-effects/step3.html)

I keep running into issues with the GLSL files. I've tried a few different loader modules. But I keep getting the same errors. Has anyone else experienced this?

```
    ERROR Failed to compile with 4 errors 5:57:14 PM
error in ./resources/assets/scripts/routes/extras/shader/fragment.glsl

Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:8)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| uniform float time;
| uniform float progress;
| uniform sampler2D texture1;

@ ./resources/assets/scripts/routes/three-test.js 11:0-53
@ ./resources/assets/scripts/main.js
@ multi ./resources/assets/build/util/…/helpers/hmr-client.js ./scripts/main.js
```

./styles/main.scss

Comment: *"You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type."*

Comment: What loaders did you try? Can you provide a full, minimised example of a GLSL file that produces the same errors?

Answer (score 3):

Taken from here:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-glsl-loader

Install this loader:

```
npm install --save-dev webpack-glsl-loader
```

And add it to your webpack configuration:

```
{
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.glsl$/,
                loader: 'webpack-glsl'
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

then simply import `fragment.glsl` like you did.

Comment: I used the following instead: `{ test: /\.(glsl|vs|fs|vert|frag)$/, exclude: /node_modules/, use: [ 'raw-loader' }`